# Java - Regex split decimal, minus, and math operation

Tags: java, regex, split

i need to split h[0] to first number("-12.0"), h[1] to operation symbol(+) and h[2] to second number(-15.3) but i don't know how it works

```
a=12.0+-15.3;
h = a.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Did you try reading about regex ?

Comment: split on spaces, why using regex?

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary i did, but not seems to be fully understand

Comment: @B.Go sorry my bad. Without whitespace

Comment: see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm with  pattern something like (maybe with extra or double \\)  = "(-?[\d.]+)([+-*/])(-?[\d.]+)"

Comment: See https://ideone.com/3gCLzl

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew whoa i think this is what i looking for! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex to match `*` or `/` anywhere n the string and `-` and `+` only when they are after a digit. In case of a match expression, you may match `+` or `-` after a word char, so, basically, you may check for a word boundary on the left: `[/*]|\b[-+]`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0iAjNj/1).

Then just split and keep the matches:

```
public static final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[/*]|\\b[-+]");

public static List<String> split(String s, Pattern pattern) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    int start = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        ret.add(s.substring(start, m.start()));
        ret.add(m.group());
        start = m.end();
    }
    if (start >= s.length()) {
        ret.add(s.substring(start));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Usage example:

```
String s = "12.0+-15.3*-45.7/+67.9";
List<String> res = split(s, regex);
System.out.println(res);
// => [12.0, +, -15.3, *, -45.7, /]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/QSLNfF)